# Insert newline to the beginning of the command if it's too long

Tags: linux, command-line, zsh

Similar to this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537230/add-newline-to-prompt-if-its-too-long#), but instead of adding a new line to the end of the prompt, add a new line to the beginning of the long command (when a command reaches to the right side of the command line window).

I believe I saw such behavior in fish as shown in this [video](https://youtu.be/sz_dsktIjt4?list=PLyzOVJj3bHQuloKGG59rS43e29ro7I57J&t=202). It only adds newline to the line containing the prompt.

I'm using zsh (`v5.8`) on Linux (`kernel: v5.10`)

Edit:

How can I implement such behavior in zsh or bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `zsh`, you could do something like:

```
zle-line-pre-redraw() {
  (( BUFFERLINES == 1 + ${#BUFFER//[^$'\n']} )) || PREDISPLAY=$'\n'
}
zle -N zle-line-pre-redraw
```

Which prepends a newline if the number of lines to display to render the buffer is greater than the number of newline characters plus 1 (meaning at least one line overflowed or PREDISPLAY was already set to newline for that buffer).

Comment: It works nicely; thank you!! Sorry, I couldn't understand your explanation. What do you mean by number of lines?

Comment: @alib, `$BUFFERLINES` contains the number of lines / rows needed to display the editing buffer. It starts at 1, if you enter a line long enough so as to wrap, it will be 2. It would also be 2 if you enter a literal newline character in the buffer (with Esc Enter or Ctrl-V Ctrl-J) so we take that into account.

Comment: Now I see!! Thanks!!!